# Expo React Native Android - Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I get the error while trying to run `npx expo run:android`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-voice/voice": "^3.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.13",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.39.8",
    "expo": "~50.0.11",
    "expo-clipboard": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.10.3",
    "expo-linking": "~6.2.2",
    "expo-router": "~3.4.8",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.26.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~2.9.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.8.2",
    "openai": "^4.28.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",
    "react-native-svg": "14.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6"
  },
```

Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-reanimated:androidJdkImage'.
> Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/johnmccants/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
> > Error while executin

I tried some of the things in this post https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3743

I tried updating my android device emulator to API Level 34

I tried editing the build.gradle file like other posts have said